# VUE change components on click

Tags: vue.js

I want to do: the main component "Test1", then click(toggle) the component "Test2", then click(toggle) the component "Test3.
But it works that the first component appears and on click immediately jumps to the third component

```
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <component v-bind:is="component" />
    <button v-on:click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <button v-on:click="toggle1()">Toggle1</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Test from './components/Test.vue'
import Test2 from './components/Test2.vue'
import Test3 from './components/Test3.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Test,
     Test2,
      Test3
  },
  data (){
    return {
      component:'Test'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.component = Test;
      this.component = Test2;
      this.component = Test3
    },
    toggle1(){
       this.component = Test2
       this.component = Test;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have two toggle methods for toggling?

Comment: It's going to component 3 becoz thats how your toggle method is written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the method as following

```
data: {
   return {
       counter: 1,
       component:'Test',
   }
},
methods: {
   toggle() {
      if (this.counter === 3) {
          this.component = 'Test';
          this.counter = 1;
      } else {
       this.counter += 1;
       this.component = `Test${this.counter}`;
     }
   }
}
```

and can have just one button to toggle

```
<button v-on:click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: partly works, but on the first click the components disappear and on the third click the second component appears

Comment: Ya there was a small error...pls check my edited answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you aiming for, but here is one solution to the problem. (not tested)

```
data: {
   return {
       counter: 1,
       component:'Test',
   }
},
methods: {
   toggle() {
      if (this.counter > 3 || this.counter == 1) {
          this.component = 'Test';
          this.counter = 1;
          return;
      }
      
      this.component = `Test${this.counter}`; 
      this.counter++;
   }
}
```

Comment: this method does not lead to anything